# mvc How can pick up month and year?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL6XF.png)
Hello, i want to replace this datepicker for one with month and years. in my model i have this piece of code:

```
[Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Select Month")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Month { get; set; }
```

and in my view i have this :

```
<div class="col-sm-9">

                        Current Month :  <span>@Convert.ToDateTime(Model.Month).ToString("MMM-yyyy")</span>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => (model.Month), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-circle " } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Month, "", new { @class = "text-danger " })
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can check minviewmode option from documentation. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#minviewmode

Answer (score 0):

In your View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.model.Month, "{0:MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Add JqueryUi script.

```
$(function () {
$("#Month").datepicker();
})
```